# Polar coordinates and parametric equation of circle in hyperbolic plane

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

We know that the parametric equation of circles of radius r and center at origin is given  by $\gamma (t) = (r\cos t, r \sin t)$ and any arbitrary closed curve can be written in the form $\gamma (t) = (r(t)\cos t, r(t) \sin t)$. Can someone help me please to write parametric equation of circle or any other closed curve in hyperbolic plane?
I was thinking about $\gamma (t) = (r(t)\cosh t, r(t) \sinh t)$, but it will not work as it has different radius than the Euclidean circle. and also origin cannot be the centre

Comment: This depends on the coordinate system you are working in. Are you using the Poincaré upper half-plane model? The Poincaré ball model? The Klein model? A different model? Please specify.

Comment: It's hyperbolic plane. Means it's the upper half plane and with the metric $\frac{dx^2+dy^2}{y^2}$